# Addition with JS Variable within HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a variable that I am declaring at the top of the JS document:

```
var poll_answer =  2;
```

However later on in the code, I am trying to append a new element with jQuery and would like to make use of this variable albeit adding '1' each time it is appended.

This is the main function:

```
function add_poll_answer_add() {
jQuery('#poll_answers').append('<tr id="poll-answer-" Answer' + poll_answer+1 + '>
    }
```

By default there are two 'answers' and hence the reason for setting the var at 2. But whenever someone appends a new element through a button, I would like them to see a new `<tr>` with the content Answer 2, 3, 4 etc. as they add more answers.

I get no errors in the debug console.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `...  Answer' + (poll_answer++) + '> ...` you need to increment the counter variable itself, not just add to a static value.

Comment: @Emissary has the Correct answer.

Comment: more like `(++poll_answer)` to get the number the question was trying to get

Comment: Ok thanks I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should define your code this way:

```
function add_poll_answer_add() {
    poll_answer = poll_answer+1;
    jQuery('#poll_answers').append('<tr id="poll-answer-" Answer' + poll + '>
}
```

Comment: is There a typo poll should be poll_answer?

Comment: yes I corrected the original question because it was a typo

Comment: thanks this works perfectly and is nice and simple to understand.